# using pymongo, how can i deal with nested json format?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

To be more specific,

I loaded the data into Mongodb by Pymongo with this script.

```
header = ['id', 'info']
for each in reader:
    row={}
    for field in header:
        row[field]=each[field]
    db.segment.insert_one(row)
```

The id column has unique Id of users and Info column is composed as nested json.
For example, here is the data set in the db

```
{
    u'_id': ObjectId('111'),
    u'id': u'123',
    u'info': {
        "TYPE": "food",
        "dishes":"166",
        "cc": "20160327 040001",
        "country": "japan",
        "money": 3521,
        "info2": [{"type"; "dishes", "number":"2"}]

    }
}
```

What i want to do is to read the value in the nested json format.
So what i did is ..

```
pipe = [{"$group":{"_id":"$id", "Totalmoney":{"$sum":"$info.money"}}}]
total_money = db.segment.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)
```

but the result of sum is always "0"for every id. 
What am i doing wrong? how can i fix it? 
I have to use mongodb because of the data size which is too big to be handled by python

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's unclear  what you are asking here. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37695700/edit) link on your question to provide more context.

Comment: I specified my question. Please help me solve the issue

Comment: One more information, When i use $unwind, It gets me error saying it is not array but string...If you want me to use $unwind

Comment: Are you sure your documents look like that when you do `db.segment.find().pretty()` in Mongo Shell?

Comment: Yes i'm pretty much sure what is the matter??

Comment: Please let me know if i'm wrong..how to insert the nested data to mongodb by pymongo and teach me the best way If you can :)